# PHP with 64-bit integers - Where do I download this?

Tags: php, windows, apache, integer, 64-bit

So I've searched around to find the download for PHP 7 that supports 64-bit integers. No luck. Obviously, I've already checked https://php.net and anything I download says `Win32`. I'm assuming that means windows 32-bit... Which I would guess supports up to 32-bit integers. Where can I download PHP 7 that supports **64-bit** integers for Windows?

Note: I'm using Apache

Answer (score 1):

> anything I download says Win32. I'm assuming that means windows 32-bit...

Normally it would, but they also use "x86" and "x64", which represent a 32-bit build and 64-bit build respectively. I'd try one of the "x64" builds to see if it does what you need.

Comment: alright Ill try it out and let you know what happens, thanks :)

Comment: When I go into file explorer and drag-and-drop the downloaded php zip files' components into `C:\xampp\php`, it says that I don't have permission. Also, note that I'm logged in as admin. What could be the issue?

Comment: Not a clue. I don't do Windows.

Comment: oh alright ill post another question but I gotta wait 90 minutes lol

Comment: *"I don't do Windows"* - That's too funny. But.. .on the more serious side of things; they did tag as such ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Sure, I know some things. I just don't know how to install beyond the basic stuff.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Agreed; that'd be off-topic for sure. They'll have to find a 64-bit version *and* install it. They just can't come back and ask us how to do it because it didn't work for them. Pretty sure that's off-topic.